Google Colabs Thread Excecution Not Working As Expected
I have been experimenting with using Google Colabs for running tasks in threads and noticed a behavior which is not reproduceable when running Jupyter with the same code locally.
Following code:
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
def done():
  print("done")

def wait_on_b():
  while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    print("1")  # b will never complete because it is waiting on a.

def wait_on_a():
  while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    print("3")  # a will never complete because it is waiting on b.


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
a = executor.submit(wait_on_b)
b = executor.submit(wait_on_a)

Runs as expected locally and outputs "1" & "3" periodically.
But colabs does not output anything.
Colabs does execute proper when waiting for the result but this is not desired in my case.
Any ideas?
I'm trying to run a thread in the background while the user is able to invoke a function with a button build with ipywidgets.
The code snippet is an example of a thread to run and print information in the output.
